# How to debug MySQL too many connections error?

Tags: mysql, database

I am running MySQL Community Server 5.6 and recently I starting to get too many connection errors. From everything I've looked at I cannot see why this is happening.

I have max_connections = 100 set in the global variables.

Whenever I check 'show processlist", I never see more than about 9 processes.

I also checked "show status where variable_name = 'Threads_connected';" and I rarely see more than 25.

Checking "show status where variable_name like  '%connections';" I see 158257. Certainly this can't be the current connections, maybe total connections but not current. I don't know where this number comes from.

So I can't see why I'm getting too many connections. What else can I check?

Comment: check `netstat` for tcp connections, and `fuser` to view the unix-domain socket to see who all's using the ip/socket.

Comment: Are you in control of the application code connecting to your database? It's common here on SO to see too many connections errors caused by code which establishes new DB connections inside a loop or recurring method call rather than creating one connection and reusing it during script execution.  I've seen it often where connections are mistakenly established as part of class instantiation, then 100's of objects instantiated.

Comment: Yes, I am in control of the code. I understand what you are referring to and I do not believe I have created that type of condition. I do open and close several connections in the code, but none that would exceed 100 times. Which is why I'm trying to find out why it is exceeding 100 now.